# Simple Dask Frequency Count

Tags: dask

I want to do a frequency count. Imagine this list of people and their age:

```
    IN [110]: b = db.from_sequence([('alex', 31), ('cassee', 31), ('Wes', 25), ('Allison', 35)])

    In [111]: b.map(lambda x: (x[1], 1))\
             .foldby(lambda x: x[0], lambda total,x: total[1]+x[1]).compute()
    Out[111]: [(31, 2), (25, (25, 1)), (35, (35, 1))]
```

The first tuple looks good `(31, 2)` meaning there were 2 occurrence of age 31. However, the format of the next two tuples is weird. I want the output to be the frequency count: `[(31, 2), (25, 1), (35, 1)]`

Answer (score 1):

The invocation you want is as follows:

```
b.pluck(1).frequencies().compute()
```

The `pluck` does the job of selecting the "age" from each element. `frequencies` does what the name suggests :)

You could have done this in other ways too:

```
b.foldby(1, lambda x, y: x + 1, 0).compute()
```

meaning, use element 1 for grouping, and within each group add 1 to the value so far for each element, starting at 0;

```
from operator import add
from collections import Counter
b.fold(lambda x, y: x + Counter([y[1]]), add, initial=Counter()).compute()
```

which is rather complicated to explain...

Comment: I didn't mention, but I DID try `frequencies`, but it seems very slow (on the order of hours) with `181283878` elements after the pluck operation.

Comment: when you run `frequencies` or `foldby` I noticed that `npartitions` goes to 1 and for the most part, only 1 core my computer is used. Am I doing something wrong?